# What's the 'Ruby way' to iterate over an array - from array[n] to array[n - 1]?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

Say I have an array of `size` 5. I want to take an index (from 0-4) as input, and iterate through the array, starting at the supplied index.

For example, if the index given was 3, I want to iterate like so:

```
arr[3]
arr[4]
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
```

I can think of plenty of ways to do this - but what's the *Ruby way* to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Array#rotate` from version 1.9.2

```
 [4,3,6,7,8].rotate(2).each{|i|print i}

 67843
```

Comment: Heh, I knew there'd be a nice way to do it :) Can't believe I missed 1.9.2 being released as well!!

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways to do it in ruby I should imagine. Not sure what *the* ruby way to do it. Maybe:

```
arr.size.times do |i|
  puts arr.at((3 + i).modulo(arr.size))
end
```

Comment: I don't think, that using indexes is Ruby-way.

Comment: Fair enough, my point was more that there are many ways to do it rather than it being possible to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your index is i:

```
(arr.from(i) + arr[0,i]).each
```